# Stacklayout doesn't load correctly external page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm developing a xamarin.forms app for my company but I have a stranger problem.
When I try to load in a stackLayout another content page, xamarin.forms doesn't load correctly the page. Probably because the page that I try to load is too big, infact if I try to load a smaller page It works correctly. (I Can't load a smaller page because I need to get a lot of data from user).

```
BigPage bigpage = new BigPage(defaultData);
               stackLayout.Children.Clear();
               stackLayout.Children.Add(bigpage);
```

[This is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRwCD.png)
In your opinion, what is the best way to solve this problem?

When the page does not load correctly, if I click on a component that opens the keyboard (like `<entry>`), the system loads the page correctly even if it is big.

Comment: you can't add a page as a child of another page, unless the parent page is a container (TabbedPage, NavigationPage, etc)

Comment: **Add to question** the XAML (or c#) that shows page creation starting at the top, down to and including stacklayout declaration. Maybe you need to tell stacklayout (or some ancestor) to fill the vertical space. AND/OR Change `BigPage` to inherit from `ContentView` instead of from `Page`. OR wrap stacklayout with a scrollview, and replace the stacklayout itself with bigpage. OR navigate to a new page, instead of trying to modify the current page.

Comment: You can only add ContentViews to a StackLayout. Please show your XAML (or code behind) for us to see what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. It's not the best solution but it works.
It was my XAML code:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
         <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout" Padding="15" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="GhostWhite" />
     </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And It is my C# code:

```
BigPage bigpage = new BigPage(defaultData);
               stackLayout.Children.Clear();
               stackLayout.Children.Add(bigpage);
```

In order to solve this problem I add in the end of the page an empty label. In this way I can load the page without problem.

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
         <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout" Padding="15" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="GhostWhite" />
         <Label Text=" " HorizontalOptions="End"/>
     </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```